# Loop não retorna os valores na tela

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um calculo de custo de compra e venda utilizando JS e PHP.

O `JS` me retorna os valores corretamente, porém **não envia para os campos**, se alguém puder me iluminar ficarei agradecido.

Segue o JS:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
          $('.calc').change(function() {
            calculaCustoCompra();
          })
          insira o código aqui
        }

        function calculaCustoCompra() {
          var i;
          for (i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
            var parametros = {
              tipo: $('#custoProdutoTipoCompra' + i).val(),
              preco: $('#custoProdutoProCompra').val(),
              perc: $('#custoProdutoPercentualCompra' + i).val(),
              valor: $('#custoProdutoValorCompra' + i).val(),
            };

            $.ajax({
              url: urlBase + '/custosProdutos/calculaCustoCompra',
              type: "POST",
              data: parametros,
              beforeSend: function() {
                waitingDialog.show('Calculando', {
                  dialogSize: 'sm'
                });
              },
              success: function(data) {
                data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                $('#custoProdutoTotal').val(data.custoTotalCompra);
                $('#custoProdutoValorCompra' + i).val(data.valor);
                $('#custoProdutoPercentualCompra' + i).val(data.perc);

                waitingDialog.hide();

              },
              error: function(error) {
                alert(error);
                waitingDialog.hide();
              }
            });

          }

        }
```

HTML:

```html
<tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          ICMS </td>
        <td>
          <div class="input select">
            <select name="data[custoProduto][TipoCompra1]" class="form-control form-control-sm calc" id="custoProdutoTipoCompra1">
              <option value="1">Somar</option>
              <option value="2" selected="selected">Subtrair</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="input text"><input name="data[custoProduto][PercentualCompra1]" value="18,00" style="width:60%;" class="form-control form-control-sm valor calc" onkeypress="return SomenteNumero(event)" type="text" id="custoProdutoPercentualCompra1"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="input text"><input name="data[custoProduto][ValorCompra1]" style="width:60%;" value="0,00" class=" form-control form-control-sm valor calc" onkeypress="return SomenteNumero(event)" type="text" id="custoProdutoValorCompra1"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          IPI </td>
        <td>
          <div class="input select">
            <select name="data[custoProduto][TipoCompra2]" class="form-control form-control-sm calc" id="custoProdutoTipoCompra2">
              <option value="1" selected="selected">Somar</option>
              <option value="2">Subtrair</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="input text"><input name="data[custoProduto][PercentualCompra2]" value="0,00" style="width:60%;" class="form-control form-control-sm valor calc" onkeypress="return SomenteNumero(event)" type="text" id="custoProdutoPercentualCompra2"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="input text"><input name="data[custoProduto][ValorCompra2]" style="width:60%;" value="0,00" class=" form-control form-control-sm valor calc" onkeypress="return SomenteNumero(event)" type="text" id="custoProdutoValorCompra2"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          ISS </td>
        <td>
          <div class="input select">
            <select name="data[custoProduto][TipoCompra3]" class="form-control form-control-sm calc" id="custoProdutoTipoCompra3">
              <option value="1" selected="selected">Somar</option>
              <option value="2">Subtrair</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="input text"><input name="data[custoProduto][PercentualCompra3]" value="0,00" style="width:60%;" class="form-control form-control-sm valor calc" onkeypress="return SomenteNumero(event)" type="text" id="custoProdutoPercentualCompra3"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="input text"><input name="data[custoProduto][ValorCompra3]" style="width:60%;" value="0,00" class=" form-control form-control-sm valor calc" onkeypress="return SomenteNumero(event)" type="text" id="custoProdutoValorCompra3"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          PIS </td>
        <td>
          <div class="input select">
            <select name="data[custoProduto][TipoCompra4]" class="form-control form-control-sm calc" id="custoProdutoTipoCompra4">
              <option value="1" selected="selected">Somar</option>
              <option value="2">Subtrair</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="input text"><input name="data[custoProduto][PercentualCompra4]" value="2,00" style="width:60%;" class="form-control form-control-sm valor calc" onkeypress="return SomenteNumero(event)" type="text" id="custoProdutoPercentualCompra4"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="input text"><input name="data[custoProduto][ValorCompra4]" style="width:60%;" value="0,00" class=" form-control form-control-sm valor calc" onkeypress="return SomenteNumero(event)" type="text" id="custoProdutoValorCompra4"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          COFINS </td>
        <td>
          <div class="input select">
            <select name="data[custoProduto][TipoCompra5]" class="form-control form-control-sm calc" id="custoProdutoTipoCompra5">
              <option value="1" selected="selected">Somar</option>
              <option value="2">Subtrair</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="input text"><input name="data[custoProduto][PercentualCompra5]" value="0,00" style="width:60%;" class="form-control form-control-sm valor calc" onkeypress="return SomenteNumero(event)" type="text" id="custoProdutoPercentualCompra5"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="input text"><input name="data[custoProduto][ValorCompra5]" style="width:60%;" value="0,00" class=" form-control form-control-sm valor calc" onkeypress="return SomenteNumero(event)" type="text" id="custoProdutoValorCompra5"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          FRETE/SEGURO </td>
        <td>
          <div class="input select">
            <select name="data[custoProduto][TipoCompra6]" class="form-control form-control-sm calc" id="custoProdutoTipoCompra6">
              <option value="1" selected="selected">Somar</option>
              <option value="2">Subtrair</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="input text"><input name="data[custoProduto][PercentualCompra6]" value="10,00" style="width:60%;" class="form-control form-control-sm valor calc" onkeypress="return SomenteNumero(event)" type="text" id="custoProdutoPercentualCompra6"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="input text"><input name="data[custoProduto][ValorCompra6]" style="width:60%;" value="0,00" class=" form-control form-control-sm valor calc" onkeypress="return SomenteNumero(event)" type="text" id="custoProdutoValorCompra6"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          II </td>
        <td>
          <div class="input select">
            <select name="data[custoProduto][TipoCompra7]" class="form-control form-control-sm calc" id="custoProdutoTipoCompra7">
              <option value="1" selected="selected">Somar</option>
              <option value="2">Subtrair</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="input text"><input name="data[custoProduto][PercentualCompra7]" value="1,60" style="width:60%;" class="form-control form-control-sm valor calc" onkeypress="return SomenteNumero(event)" type="text" id="custoProdutoPercentualCompra7"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="input text"><input name="data[custoProduto][ValorCompra7]" style="width:60%;" value="0,00" class=" form-control form-control-sm valor calc" onkeypress="return SomenteNumero(event)" type="text" id="custoProdutoValorCompra7"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Os elementos estão me retornando o calculo corretamente, por exemplo:

> {"custoTotalCompra":"17,6400","valor":"3,36","perc":"16,00"}
>   {"custoTotalCompra":"23,1000","valor":"2,10","perc":"10,00"}

Mas os campos não estão sendo preenchidos com os valores informados.

Comment: Bota o código HTML renderizado, fica melhor pra simular.

Comment: Opa, coloquei ele

Comment: Seu console está mostrando algum erro?

Comment: nenhum, mas eu mantive o alert('i'); pra conferir, e ele aparece apenas o numero 7 varias vezes, deveria mostrar, 1,2,3,4,5,6 nao?

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver o problema com a seguinte solução:

```
function calculaCustoCompra(){
for(var i = 1;i < 10;i++){
    (function(){
        var id = i;
        var parametros = {
            tipo: $('#custoProdutoTipoCompra'+id).val(),         
            preco: $('#custoProdutoProCompra').val(),     
            perc: $('#custoProdutoPercentualCompra'+id).val(),        
            valor: $('#custoProdutoValorCompra'+id).val(),   
        };

            $.ajax({
                url: urlBase + '/custosProdutos/calculaCustoCompra',
                type: "POST",
                data: parametros,
                beforeSend: function(){
                    waitingDialog.show('Calculando',{dialogSize: 'sm'});
                },
                success: function (data) {   
                    data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    $('#custoProdutoTotal').val(data.custoTotalCompra);
                    $('#custoProdutoValorCompra'+id).val(data.valor);
                    $('#custoProdutoPercentualCompra'+id).val(data.perc);
                    alert(id);
                    console.log(data);

                    waitingDialog.hide();

                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert(error); 
                    waitingDialog.hide();      
                }
            });
    }) ();
};
```

}

adicionando o function(){

`for(var i = 1;i < 10;i++){
        (function(){`

Answer (score 0):

Opa, vamos tentar resolver o seu problema.

Tente trocar o código:

```
  $('#custoProdutoTotal').val(data.custoTotalCompra);
```

Por:

```
  $('#custoProdutoTotal').html(data.custoTotalCompra);
```

Comment: Sem efeito, com .val() aparece o ultimo numero total "gerado", porem com html nem isso.

Comment: Faça um `console.log(data)` e mostre a saída.

Comment: `Object { custoTotalCompra: "21,0000", valor: "0,00", perc: "0,00" }`
custosProdutos.js:97:29
`Object { custoTotalCompra: "21,4200", valor: "0,42", perc: "2,00" }`
custosProdutos.js:97:29
`Object { custoTotalCompra: "21,0000", valor: "0,00", perc: "0,00" }`
custosProdutos.js:97:29
`Object { custoTotalCompra: "18,9000", valor: "2,10", perc: "10,00" }`
custosProdutos.js:97:29
`Object { custoTotalCompra: "21,0000", valor: "0,00", perc: "0,00" }`
custosProdutos.js:97:29
`Object { custoTotalCompra: "21,0000", valor: "0,00", perc: "0,00" }`
custosProdutos.js:97:29